# how to read the output of a function as an object

Tags: html, arrays, string, object, charts

Here is the output of my function sam() in HTML:

```
["2020-02-14", 324.7300, 325.9800, 322.8500, 324.9500, 20028447],
["2020-02-13", 324.1900, 326.2200, 323.3500, 324.8700, 23686892],
["2020-02-12", 321.4700, 327.2200, 321.4700, 327.2000, 28432573],
["2020-02-11", 323.6000, 323.9000, 318.7100, 319.6100, 23580780],
["2020-02-10", 314.1800, 321.5500, 313.8500, 321.5500, 27337215],
```

I am trying to get that very output of sam() to be read as an object in this line of code below.

```
"data": [
           sam()   ],
```

At the moment `sam()` in that location keeps outputting that above sequence of dates and price numbers. I need for `sam()` in that location to be read so that the above sequence would be integrated into the stock chart that I am working on. If I add all of that code as a non-string into the `"data"[     ]`, it will print out the stock chart with the dates and prices, but when I simply use the function `sam()` in there, it doesn't print out the chart. It only does dates and numbers

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'm really confused what you are getting and what you expect when you call a function inside an array? Is this Javascript? There isn't a tag for it. Maybe read [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and modify your question.

Comment: try it like this --> `"data": sam()`

Comment: @WhiteHat wow, I didn't even think of that. I just tried it but it still prints out the dates and numbers. I even tried `eval(sam())` and that didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Here is the entire code that uses the `sam()` function. When you execute it, it will output a sequence of dates and numbers. When you copy and paste that output into the line of code near the bottom labeled `"data" : [      ]`, it will output a nice looking stock chart using the dates and numbers. I need a function that can do the same.

```
<html> 

<head> 
<script data-require="jquery@2.1.4" data-semver="2.1.4" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="highstock@0.0.1" data-semver="0.0.1" src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
  <script data-require="highstock@0.0.1" data-semver="0.0.1" src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <title> 
        How to get the array of dates between 
        two dates in JavaScript ? 
    </title> 
</head> 

<body style = "text-align:center;"> 
 <div id="myData"></div>

  <div id="demo"></div>
<div id="demo1"></div>
<script>var tday=["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];
var tmonth=["-01-","-02-","-03-","-04-","-05-","-06-","-07-","-08-","-09-","-10-","-11-","-12-"];

function GetClock(){
var d=new Date();
var nday=d.getDay(),nmonth=d.getMonth(),ndate=d.getDate(),nyear=d.getFullYear();
var nhour=d.getHours(),nmin=d.getMinutes(),nsec=d.getSeconds(),ap;

if(nhour==0){ap=" AM";nhour=12;}
else if(nhour<12){ap=" AM";}
else if(nhour==12){ap=" PM";}
else if(nhour>12){ap=" PM";nhour-=12;}

if(nmin<=9) nmin="0"+nmin;
if(nsec<=9) nsec="0"+nsec;

var clocktext=""+nyear +tmonth[nmonth] +ndate +"";
document.getElementById('clockbox').innerHTML= clocktext;

}

GetClock();
setInterval(GetClock,1000);</script>


    <script> 
function heavy(){
        var today = new Date("2014-10-01"); //YYYY-MM-DD


var startDate = new Date("2014-10-01");


var endDate = new Date("2016-10-10" );

     //YYYY-MM-DD

var getDateArray = function(start, end) {
    var arr = new Array();


     while (startDate < end) {
        arr.push(new Date(startDate));
        startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 1);

    }

    return arr.reverse().toLocaleString().replace(new RegExp('/', 'g'), '-').replace(new RegExp("8:", 'g'), '').replace(new RegExp("00", 'g'), '').replace(new RegExp("PM", 'g'), '').replace(new RegExp("AM", 'g'), '').replace(new RegExp(",", 'g'), '').replace(new RegExp(":", 'g'), '');
}

var dateArr = getDateArray(startDate, endDate);

// Output

for (var i = 0; i < dateArr.length; i++) {

  document.write(  dateArr[i]   );

}



}
    </script> 
<script>
function heavy1(){
  var cars = [["2020-02-13"], ["2020-02-12"]];
  var text = "";
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
    text += cars[i] + "<br>";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;}

</script>
<script>

    function sam(){    
        fetch('https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=MSFT&outputsize=full&apikey=demo')
            .then(function (response) {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(function (data) {
                appendData(data);
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                console.log('error: ' + err);
            });

        function appendData(data) {
            var mainContainer = document.getElementById("myData");
var arrw = ["2020-02-14",
    "2020-02-13",
    "2020-02-12",
    "2020-02-11",
    "2020-02-10",
    "2020-02-07",
    "2020-02-06",
    "2020-02-05",
    "2020-02-04",
    "2020-02-03",
    "2020-01-31",
    "2020-01-30",
    "2020-01-29",
    "2020-01-28",
    "2020-01-27",
    "2020-01-24",
    "2020-01-23",
    "2020-01-22",
    "2020-01-21",];
            for (var i = 0; i < arrw.length; i++) {



               var joe = '[' +"\""+ arrw[i]+ "\"" +  "," + "     "  + data['Time Series (Daily)'][arrw[i]]['1. open']+"," + "   " +data['Time Series (Daily)'][arrw[i]]['2. high']+","  + "   " +data['Time Series (Daily)'][arrw[i]]['3. low']+","+ "   " +data['Time Series (Daily)'][arrw[i]]['4. close']+","+ "   " +data['Time Series (Daily)'][arrw[i]]['5. volume' ] + ']' +  ","  ;
                document.write(joe);



        }}}
    </script>
<div id="container"></div>
  <script>

    var json = {
      "dataset": {

        "data": [
          sam()
        ],

      }
    };

    var hiJson = json.dataset.data.map(function(d) {
      return [new Date(d[0]).getTime(), d[4]]
    });

    // Create the chart
    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
      rangeSelector: {
        selected: 1
      },
      title: {
        text: 'MS Stock Price'
      },
      series: [{
        name: 'MS',
        data: hiJson,
        tooltip: {
          valueDecimals: 2
        }
      }]
    });
  </script>
</body> 

</html>
```